# How to use ClipPath so it does not clip outside the child widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am trying to clip my widget according to a custom Path but the my CustomClipper is too big for my child widget. How can i resize my Custom Clipper to size of my child widget? Is there any other way to clip a widget with a Flutter path?

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: ClipPath(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.pink,
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
            ),
            clipper: MyCustomClipper(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


class MyCustomClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path()
      ..moveTo(1305.0, 3204.0)
      ..cubicTo(874.0, 3124.0, 514.0, 2886.0, 263.0, 2515.0)
      ..cubicTo(166.0, 2371.0, 81.0, 2167.0, 34.0, 1965.0)
      ..cubicTo(-2.0, 1804.0, -12.0, 1523.0, 15.0, 1354.0)
      ..cubicTo(112.0, 733.0, 556.0, 219.0, 1136.0, 56.0)
      ..cubicTo(1306.0, 8.0, 1399.0, -3.0, 1590.0, 2.0)
      ..cubicTo(1852.0, 9.0, 2049.0, 59.0, 2259.0, 171.0)
      ..cubicTo(2711.0, 412.0, 3012.0, 834.0, 3096.0, 1346.0)
      ..cubicTo(3118.0, 1476.0, 3120.0, 1734.0, 3101.0, 1855.0)
      ..cubicTo(3037.0, 2259.0, 2839.0, 2616.0, 2541.0, 2864.0)
      ..cubicTo(2439.0, 2949.0, 2338.0, 3013.0, 2205.0, 3076.0)
      ..cubicTo(2077.0, 3136.0, 2006.0, 3162.0, 1878.0, 3191.0)
      ..cubicTo(1755.0, 3220.0, 1428.0, 3227.0, 1305.0, 3204.0)
      ..close()
      ..moveTo(1780.0, 2271.0)
      ..cubicTo(2047.0, 2181.0, 2235.0, 1954.0, 2268.0, 1685.0)
      ..cubicTo(2276.0, 1610.0, 2270.0, 1489.0, 2254.0, 1437.0)
      ..cubicTo(2181.0, 1194.0, 2015.0, 1018.0, 1780.0, 938.0)
      ..cubicTo(1691.0, 908.0, 1676.0, 906.0, 1550.0, 906.0)
      ..cubicTo(1424.0, 906.0, 1409.0, 908.0, 1320.0, 938.0)
      ..cubicTo(1020.0, 1042.0, 830.0, 1302.0, 830.0, 1609.0)
      ..cubicTo(830.0, 1942.0, 1060.0, 2216.0, 1405.0, 2296.0)
      ..cubicTo(1443.0, 2305.0, 1504.0, 2308.0, 1575.0, 2306.0)
      ..cubicTo(1666.0, 2303.0, 1701.0, 2297.0, 1780.0, 2271.0)
      ..close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

Comment: you get `Size size` inside your `getClip` function. you can use it to get the size allowed for drawing. also, if you pass the size while clipping or wrap it with sized widget, you get the size. comment if you want an example.

Comment: Hey @Doc, Wrapping the ClipPath widget with a SizedBox widget didn't do the job. Nor passing the custom size parameter in getClip function. I could really use an example here.

Comment: so you want to have clippath dependent on your child widget?

Comment: posted a sample code

Answer (score 2):

This code with custom shape to apply widget in ClipPath

```
ClipPath( 
     clipper: MyClipper(),
     child: Image.asset( "assets/image.jpg", ),
   ),

class MyClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
    @override
    Path getClip(Size size) {
      final path = Path();
      path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);
      path.lineTo(size.width * 0.75, size.height);
      path.lineTo(size.width * 0.25, size.height);
      path.close();
      return path;
    }
  
    @override
    bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper oldClipper) {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

A basic code which shows a triangle clipped to half the dimensions of the child

```
main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: SO()));

class SO extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(width: 1,color: Colors.red)),//this container shows the actual size of the child widget marked by red border and it is w:200 by h:400
        child: ClipPath(
            clipper: CC(),//clips to half the size i.e. w->100,h->200
            child: Container(
                color: Colors.purple,
              width: 200,
              height: 400,
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CC extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var w = size.width;
    var h = size.height;
    print(w); //should be 200
    print(h); //should be 400

    //clips a triangle to half size of child
    Path p = Path();
    p.moveTo(0, 0);
    p.lineTo(w / 2, 0);
    p.lineTo(w / 2, h / 2);
    p.close();
    return p;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper oldClipper) => false;
}
enter code here
```